# Unable to pass blob into iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

To work around some issues (problems upgrading firebase 2 to 3), I had to use an iframe to do certain tasks in this case, uploading to Firebase Storage.

I notice I cannot pass a Blob into an iframe function? When I did in the same domain

```
canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
    var upload = firebase.storage().ref().child('testing.jpg').put(blob)
    upload.on('state_changed', function(snapshot) {
        console.log(snapshot)
    }, function(err) {
        console.error(err.stack)
        reject(err)
    }, function() {
        console.log('uploaded to', upload.snapshot.downloadURL)
        resolve(upload.snapshot.downloadURL)
    })
}, 'image/jpeg')
```

It works. But when I pass the blob into an iframe function

```
canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
    document.getElementById('iframe').contentWindow.uploadImage('testing.jpg', blob)
        .then(function(url) {
            console.log('>>>', url)
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            console.error(err.stack)
        })
}, 'image/jpeg')
```

It fails with

> Firebase Storage: Invalid argument in `put` at index 0: Expected Blob or File.

It seems like when a Blob is passed into an iframe it gets corrupt or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like theres something weird going on when passing objects, so I passed base64 string instead.

`iframe.contentWindow.uploadImage(path, canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg'))`